# How can i download only the files from last commit from git to a folder?

Tags: git, ant, salesforce, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I am trying to get the files changed in the last commit in git and put them into a separate folder. Is there an ant script or shell script that does this job?

To give you a context, I am trying to implement a continous integration and delivery pipeline to release only the changed files in a git branch to  salesforce environment. I am making use of ant build.xml and force.com migration tool to achieve this. The git branch currently contains the full metadata of sandbox . I dont want to deploy the entire metadata when doing a release - hence the requirement to get only the changed files and deploy only those files to the target salesforce environment.

Any help would be appreciated. I am kind of blocked at this stage with no clue how to proceed.

Comment: I want to implement same thing. Has you been able to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with a human-oriented answer, but note that you're trying to build something that a *machine* will do, and machines are generally very fast idiots that follow your directions even if you have hit a weird case where they should do something smarter.

---

Assuming you have the full repository (or at least a shallow repository with enough commits), use `git diff --name-only` or `git diff --name-status` to extract the names of the files of interest:

```
$ git diff --name-status master~1 master
M       Documentation/RelNotes/2.19.0.txt
```

for instance tells me that between the commit one graph-step in the first-parent direction *before* the current `master`, and `master` itself, exactly one file changed, via modification.

The two commits being compared here are the result of `git rev-parse` on each of these two arguments, so if you have hash IDs, you're in better shape than if you just have a branch name.  Branch names move in ways that may not be predictable, i.e., there's no obvious guarantee that your previous deployment was `master~1`.  Commit hash IDs do not: if you know that you previous deployment was, say:

```
$ git rev-parse master
b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f
```

and at some point in the future your *next* deployment is some other commit whose hash ID you obtain (perhaps via `git rev-parse` just like this), it does not matter if someone did something scary with the name `master`, such as to rewrite commit history, you can still compare the correct two commits.

Now let's get into some of the complications.

#### The status might be "deleted", or "added", or something more complicated

Let's pick two different commits to compare:

```
$ git diff --name-status 3c6151dad310db71f599dbfbac329fa961f29794 979f030359f6830fbaebd0c76e9aad5f86993fef
M       .gitignore
M       .mailmap
A       .travis.yml
M       Documentation/CodingGuidelines
```

Three files here were modified as usual, but one, `.travis.yml`, is *new*.  It was *created*, not changed, across this commit-pair.

(I snipped a lot out here.)

```
R100    t/t5701-clone-local.sh  t/t5605-clone-local.sh
R100    t/t5702-clone-options.sh        t/t5606-clone-options.sh
R100    t/t5704-bundle.sh       t/t5607-clone-bundle.sh
R100    t/t5705-clone-2gb.sh    t/t5608-clone-2gb.sh
R100    t/t5706-clone-branch.sh t/t5609-clone-branch.sh
R100    t/t5707-clone-detached.sh       t/t5610-clone-detached.sh
R063    t/t5708-clone-config.sh t/t5611-clone-config.sh
R100    t/t5709-clone-refspec.sh        t/t5612-clone-refspec.sh
R099    t/t5710-info-alternate.sh       t/t5613-info-alternate.sh
```

These files were *renamed*.

```
D       t/t5700-clone-reference.sh
```

This file was *deleted*.

There are other statuses you can come across, and you should decide what to do with them.

#### `git diff` is a *porcelain* command; you want *plumbing* commands

You need to do a machine reading of the output from `git diff`, but `git diff` is—as unlikely as it might seem from these examples—actually aimed at producing output readable by humans, rather than output readable by machines.  Git calls these user-oriented commands *porcelain*, with the machine-oriented ones called *plumbing*.

This has several side effects.  The most important is this one:  **User configurations *change* the way `git diff` output appears.**

In particular, that status of `R` (for renamed) appears if and only if you enable *rename detection*.  Rename detection is controlled by the user's `diff.renames` and `diff.renameLimit` settings by default.  The underlying defaults, should the user not have configured a setting, depend on the Git version as well.  So instead of `git diff`, you should use `git diff-tree`, which is a plumbing command.

It is more obnoxious to use, because you have to specify everything, especially the `-r` (recursive) flag to find out what is different inside different sub-trees.  You should also probably use the `-z` flag to have it zero-terminate file names, so that you can handle those reliably in all cases.

If you use submodules, think about how you want to deal with those.

In all cases, read [the `git diff-tree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html) carefully.